# Ignore ORIG_HEAD in zsh git autocomplete

Tags: git, zsh, zsh-completion

I use oh-my-zsh and git autocompletion.

If I type `git checkout org` and hit TAB I get these results:

> ```
> ORIG_HEAD
> origin/HEAD
> origin/mybranch
> ```

How can I make the autocompletion to ignore `ORIG_HEAD`?

Comment: I just added a bounty because I'm very much interested in an answer to this :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*' ignored-patterns '*ORIG_HEAD'
```

This will ignore all files ending with `ORIG_HEAD` when multiple files exist.

Comment: If you want to scope this a little bit tighter then you can use `zstyle ':completion:*:*:git*:*' ignored-patterns '*ORIG_HEAD'`

Answer (score 0):

1. You could edit /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git and remove ORIG_HEAD in the following line (line 5091 for me):

   `for f in HEAD FETCH_HEAD ORIG_HEAD MERGE_HEAD; do`
2. You could remove `.git/ORIG_HEAD` :)